# How do I access the inner child control of my user control in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, user-controls

I have a very simple control. It just displays a textbox.

```
<my:usercontrol x:Name="myControl" />
```

I would like to use my control as following:

```
<my:usercontrol x:Name="myControl">
    <sdk:Label x:Name="InnerControl" Content="Hello World" />
</my:usercontrol>
```

How do I gain access to the "InnerControl" from within "myControl"?

Comment: you mean by code(-behind)?

Comment: Yes, I would like to access it using code behind on myControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you defined a name for your Label, you can access it in the codebehind file of your UserControl by using its name

Example:

```
// ctor
public partial class usercontrol : UserControl {
  InitializeComponent();
  var Label = this.Content; // This is the label (InnerControl)
}
```